# Javascript, cannot find variable for if statement using coordinates from Geolocation API to cause an event

Tags: javascript, if-statement, geolocation, coordinates

I am using Geolocation API to find a user's coordinates, and then based on those coordinates redirecting them to the appropriate webpage based on their coordinates. But I am struggling set up the if-statement that will redirect to another webpage. What is the variable that will cause the if-statement to redirect to the user to the correct page?

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  if (showPosition(latitude) > 34) {
      console.log("It worked");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you used `showPosition(latitude)` which is the function name instead of  the parameter `position` which holds the coordinates data

```
if (position.coords.latitude > 34) {
   console.log("It worked");
}
```